# how to use memset for double dimentional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, memset

I have a Double dim. array:

```
 alarm_1_active_buffer[MAX_NUM_ALARMS][MAX_ALARM_STRING_SIZE];
```

I want to clear the buffer before filling it.
Like this :

```
 for(index=0; index<MAX_NUM_ALARMS ; index++)
    {
        memset(&alarm_1_active_buffer[index], 0, MAX_ALARM_STRING_SIZE);
        memset(&alarm_1_active_buffer[index],string, MAX_ALARM_STRING_SIZE);
    }
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Since the arrays are laid in continuos address spaces, you don't have to do anything special for 2d arrays. You can simply use `memset(alarm_1_active_buffer, 0, MAX_NUM_ALARMS * MAX_ALARM_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(type of alarm_1_active_buffer));`.

Comment: Umm..`alarm_1_active_buffer[index] = 0`

Comment: You can just clear the entire array at once -- you don't need to iterate through the outer array and clear each index.

Comment: Tip:  When using the `sizeof` operator, refer to the variable itself, dereferencing if needed, instead of naming the type explicitly (e.g., `sizeof **alarm_1_active_buffer` instead of `sizeof (char)`).  This prevents bugs that crop up when the variable's type changes and one of the `sizeof` instances that references the old type isn't changed along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure to `#include <string.h>` first:

```
memset(alarm_1_active_buffer, 0, sizeof(alarm_1_active_buffer));
```

This method works regardless of the type of elements in the array.